# MVC design and form submission: URL showed to users

Tags: forms, post-redirect-get, user-feedback

I have a question about some MVC design and form submission. I have some problem when I want to save a resource.

For example I have a controller name `vehicle` with the given methods :

```
vehicle
  |-- list
      `-- GET  - Display the list of vehicle.
  |-- add
      |-- GET  - Display the form for adding a vehicle.
      `-- POST - Save the added vehicle.
```

My problem is that after the user has saved a vehicle, I want to go back to the list of vehicle displaying a notification. `view_model.add_notification` is a method that displays a notification on the view.

a) I redirect the user to `vehicle/list?success=1` and I call `view_model.add_notification` when I see the `success` in the query string
*problem*: the URL will contains the `success=1`.

b) Inside the `POST` request `vehicle/add` I display the list after saving the vehicle and call `view_model.add_notification`.
*problem*: the URL will be `vehicle/add`

c) I changed my controller to this

```
vehicle
  |-- list
      `-- GET  - Display the list of vehicle.
      `-- POST - Save the added vehicle.
  |-- add
      |-- GET  - Display the form for adding a vehicle.
```

So I can call `view_model.add_notification('success')` and then display the list and the URL will be fine.
*problem*: I feel this is not correct design to put the saving code in the `list` method.

Please, can you have some input for me on how is the best way to design that ? To sum up the proposition I wrote:
a) bad url
b) bad url
c) bad design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a session var like

```
$_SESSION['success'] = true;
```

and redirect the user to the list page. Then you can

```
if( isset($_SESSION['success']) ) {

    // Do what you want to do when success is set

    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
```